# javascript is not working in my wordpress on (wamp + windows 7)

Tags: wordpress

i installed wordpress on my localhost (wamp on windows 7) but javascript is not working on my admin area

any help ?

**EDIT**

i'm tracking the problem

it seems it's from /wp-admin/loadscripts.php line 123 "get_file" function .. when it's getting the javascript from the file it replaces " with \" it did preg_replace but it seems that there is something else .. i tried different function file_get_contents for example and still the same problem

here is 1 of the errors from firefox error window

```
Error: syntax error
Source File: mylocalhost/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load=jquery,utils&ver=0e4de088c1d51cff99f6e17399d2c995
Line: 21, Column: 58
Source Code:
Wa=/^(\\s|\\u00A0)+|(\\s|\\u00A0)+$/g,Xa=/^<(\\w+)\\s*\\/?>(?:<\\/\\1>)?$/,P=navigator.userAgent,xa=false,Q=[],L,$=Object.prototype.toString,aa=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,ba=Array.prototype.push,R=Array.prototype.slice,ya=Array.prototype.indexOf;c.fn
```

Comment: Not enough info to give any useful answers

Comment: what info you want ? ... sorry but there is nothing to provide i just installed wordpress and javascript is not working ..... i though it would be a common problem

Comment: What does _"javascript is not working"_ mean? JavaScript runs **in the browser**. Is JavaScript disabled in your browser? See also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved that !!

when we open a javascript file and output in windows we need stripslashes and everything will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is often conflicting plugins. If you installed any new plugins recently, try deactivating them one by one and see whether you can find the culprit.

Also, look in Firebug's "Net" tab to see whether there are any missing resources.

Comment: thanks for your answer my friend, but it's a fresh copy !! .. i uploaded it on my server and it works perfectly

Comment: @From.ME strange... Then it's something more complex than that. Still check whether there are any missing resources

Answer (score 0):

stripslashes was the culprit. Spot on! If you guys have installed WAMP and are running wordpress on it. Go to WAMP > PHP Settings > and uncheck all Magic quotes options if they are checked and restart WAMP, You are good to go. Cheers.